# CE Device platform SDK not showing up in VS2008

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2008, mobile, sdk, windows-ce

So I've installed VS2010 express for desktop development, then VS2008 for mobile development (I'm developing for a Honeywell Dolphin 6100), then the platform and device SDKs for the Honeywell stuff.

The SDK files have installed to the right place, but it doesn't show up as a target device for debugging in VS2008.

Any idea what gives?

Cheers

Comment: Always, always, always install in the order MS released products.  VS08 after VS10 is likely going to break device development stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that, when running on Windows 7, it can help to run the SDK installers from an elevated command prompt (Run As Administrator). The SDK build tools in Platform Builder need to use custom actions to update Visual Studio's configuration files, and I'm not certain they're set to the correct values to run under an account with rights to modify the files.

The platform information is defined in %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\vcpackages\WCE.VCPlatform.config, or %ProgramFiles(x86)% if you're running a 64-bit OS. I've also found that some installers apply the settings to VS 2005, but not to VS 2008: if you do have both versions installed, you can copy from one to the other.